# NLP & ML Text Extraction

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, regression, svm, naivebayes

I have some user chat data and categorised in various categories, the problem is there are a lot of algorithm generated categories, please see example below:

```
Message | Category
I want to play cricket | Play cricket
I wish to watch cricket | Watch cricket
I want to play cricket outside | Play cricket outside
```

As you can see Categories (essentially phrases) are extracted from the text itself,
based on my data there are 10,000 messages with approx 4,500 unique catgories.
Is there any suitable algorithm which can give me good prediction accuracy in such cases.

Comment: Are all the examples like that? (i.e: the categories are mostly "extracted from" or contained in the message).

Comment: yes, they are extracted from the text itself any specific algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I habitually use OpenNLP's DocumentCategorizer for tasks like this, but StanfordNLP core I think does some similar stuff. OpenNLP uses Maximum Entropy for this, but there are many ways to do it.

First some thoughts on the amount of unique labels. Basically you only have a few samples per class, and that is generally a bad thing: your classifier is going to give sucky results no matter what it is if you try to do it the way you are implying because of overlap and / or underfitting. So here's what i've done before in a similar situation: separate concepts into different thematic classifiers, then assemble the best scores for each. For example, based on what you wrote above, you may be able to detect OUTSIDE or INSIDE with one classification model, and then WATCHING CRICKET vs PLAYING CRICKET in another. Then at runtime, you would pass the text into both classifiers, and take the best hit for each to assemble a single category. Pseudo code:

```
DoccatModel outOrIn = new DoccatModel(modelThatDetectsOutsideOrInside);
DoccatModel cricketMode = new DoccatModel(modelThatDetectsPlayingOrWatchingCricket)
String stringToDetectClassOf = "Some dude is playing cricket outside, he sucks";
String outOrInCat = outOrIn.classify(stringToDetectClassOf);
String cricketModeCat = cricketMode .classify(stringToDetectClassOf);
String best = outOrInCat + " " + cricketModeCat ;
```

you get the point I think.
Also some other random thoughts:
- Use a text index to explore the amount of data you get back to figure out how to break up the categories.
- You want a few hundred examples for each model

let me know if you want me to give you some code examples from OpenNLP if you are doing this in Java